# Mysql FIND_IN_SET in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

The below query does not use the index and type in explain plan is 'ALL'

EXPLAIN EXTENDED

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(fname,' ',lname)) 
FROM employee WHERE FIND_IN_SET(emp_id,'111582,111624')>0;
```

is there is any way to change the query for use the index.

Explain plan Output:

```
 id : 1
 select_type :SIMPLE
 table  : employee 
 type   : ALL
 possible_keys  : {null}
 key    : {null}
 key_len    : {null}
 ref    : {null}
 rows  : 546
 filtered : 100
 Extra: Using where
```

kindly suggest me to improve the query to use the index.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: And your Index is on which field?

Comment: the emp_id is the primary key column which has the index

Answer (score 3):

`FIND_IN_SET` is a string function and (in most of the cases) will result a full table scan...

Use:

```
WHERE emp_id IN (111582,111624)
```

Comment: It good answer. but i am storing the 111582,111624 in a separate column. what is the case for the WHERE FIND_IN_SET(emp_id,comma_separated_column_name)>0;   comma_separated_column_name - here the values are stored as 1212,13224,121213

Comment: 1) Do the string splitting in the progamming language you use.. ooor... 2) Fix your database schema, normalize the data.

Answer (score 3):

Since the answer comes way too late, I was also in the same requirement and found that **FIND_IN_SET** still works for column as well.
Example (1 is the emp_id)

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1,comma_separated_column_name)
```

Here is my example
[image]

The query selects all trips that have 1 in the weekend column